# User Input with API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I have a form where a user can input the latitude and longitude (coordinate). 
What i want to do is to display the information based on the below REST API:
https://rest.soilgrids.org/query.html

So here is what i created.

```html
<p>
  Latitude : <input id='lat'/> <br/>
  Longitude: <input id='lon'/> <br/>
  <button id='submit'>Submit<button/>
 <p/>
```

So how do i extract the input and and made it display the information that are available based on the API. I am beginner in this so would need help in JS

Comment: I will need more information, I even tried hitting that API but it just returns with Bad Requests so I am assuming it needs credentials or something, anyways I think the question is a little broad and it would be helpful if you explained more of what you want to do and even had examples and code.

Comment: Oh in addition I don't mean to imply you should share API keys or anything, don't ever do that. Code examples would be limited to the parts you need help with and are related to what you are stuck on.

Comment: I don't think you need any API key. For example https://rest.soilgrids.org/query?lon=1&lat=2

Comment: thank you on the advice, i have updated the question and also the API is available on the link given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>

    </style>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label>Latitute</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="lat">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label>longitute</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="long">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">

                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="search" value="get Info">
                </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#search").click(function(){
                let lat = $("#lat").val();
                let long = $("#long").val();
                if(lat == "" || long==""){
                    alert("please enter lat and long to get info");
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"GET",
                        url:`https://rest.soilgrids.org/query?lon=${long}&lat=${lat}`,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success:function(response){
                                console.log(response);
                        },
                        error:function(jqXHR, exception){
                            console.log("error");
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Try it

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform an Ajax call to get data from an API.

Assuming that you have jQuery in your script, an example will be:

```
// The code will only run on form submit
$("#form").on("submit", (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    // Abbreviate on how you get the longitude / latitude 
    const longitude = ...
    const latitude = ...
    const url = "https://rest.soilgrids.org/query?lon=" + logitude + "&lat=" + latitude 
    $.ajax(url, {
        method: "GET" // You need to read the documentation of the API provider to see if it is a POST or GET call
        // There are more option that you can set. Read the documentation of jquery,
        success: (data) => {
            // This is where you perform effect after you get the data from API
        }
    })
})
```

See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for more detail

**Edit**

Just saw your code. Some minor change should be made to make this better:

```
// Warp it into a <form> block so that it will response to "Enter" Key
<form id="form">
    Latitude : <input id='lat'/> <br/>
    Longitude: <input id='lon'/> <br/>
    // Good habit to state the type of a button
    <button type="submit" id='submit'>Submit<button/>
</form>
```